# Is it legal to make an audio recording in a United Kingdom workplace with one party consent

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, privacy, recording, workplace

My office it's very loud. I complained to my line manager and as a proof I have recorded a few seconds of this noisy environment. At the time of recording there were other colleagues in the room.

My line manager wants to take disciplinary action against me because according to him I have violated some laws.

The recording was too short and with a poor quality that any voice and person can be recognized, also there are any statements on my contract about recording etc.

Did making this recording break any laws?

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ might provide some answers related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

So doing a quick check on U.K. consent Laws, you might have run afoul of them.  A company can only record it's employees if they make their employees aware of the recording.  They need not record the customers.  I would hesitate to say you actually broke the law, as this is convoluted by the fact that you are an employee, not an employer of the people recorded.  Additionally, this law is with regards to phone conversations, and generally One Party Consent allows for recording to any conversation which you are privy too, including office babble.